# Como mudar uma cor com base na posição de scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Olá!
Já há um tempo que ando à procura e encontro várias coisas, mas para o que eu quero especificamente, não.
No meu blog do Tumblr, eu quero por uma border à volta dos posts com aproximadamente 5px, cuja cor mude com base na posição de scroll. Pretendo que seja desvanecido e que por isso tenha muitas cores.
Devo criar uma div para a border certo? Mas como e que css ou javascript depois uso para fazer a "animação"?
Obrigada e peço desculpa por ser meio noob

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o evento $.scroll do jQuery e a propriedade scrollTop para saber onde a barra está e usar esse valor para calcular uma cor de sua escolha. Fiz esse exemplo para ti:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
 var posicao = $(window).scrollTop();
 var cor = Math.round(posicao / 1000);
 $('#post').css('border-color', pegarCor(cor));
});
pegarCor = function(cor){
  switch(cor){
    case 1:
      return "#ff0ff0";
      break;
    case 2:
      return "#00aabc";
      break;
    case 3:
      return "#00ee54";
      break;
    case 4:
      return "#334454";
      break;
    case 5:
      return "#ff00ff";
      break;
    default:
      return "#00aa12";
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
#post{
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: #000;
  position: fixed;
  width:200px;
  height:100px
}
body{
height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="post">
Esse é o seu post
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado! Não está a resultar, porque está a fazer uma border à volta de todos os posts... Para além disso, deixou de fazer scroll, porque tinha a posição dos posts fixed (mas já pus relative e já faz scroll, mas não muda a cor)

Comment: Agradecia resposta

Answer (score 0):

Aproveitei o mesmo código que o LF Ziron postou e modifiquei para que conforme a página va descendo usando o scroll, as divs mudarão de cor

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
 var posicao = $(window).scrollTop();
 var cor = Math.round(posicao / 1000);
 $('.post').css('border-color', pegarCor(cor));
});
pegarCor = function(cor){
  switch(cor){
    case 1:
      return "#ff0ff0";
      break;
    case 2:
      return "#00aabc";
      break;
    case 3:
      return "#00ee54";
      break;
    case 4:
      return "#334454";
      break;
    case 5:
      return "#ff00ff";
      break;
    default:
      return "#00aa12";
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
.post{
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: #000;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
body{
height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post">
Esse é o seu post
</div>
<div class="post">
Esse é o seu post
</div>
<div class="post">
Esse é o seu post
</div>
<div class="post">
Esse é o seu post
</div>
<div class="post">
Esse é o seu post
</div>
<div class="post">
Esse é o seu post
</div>
<div class="post">
Esse é o seu post
</div>
<div class="post">
Esse é o seu post
</div>
<div class="post">
Esse é o seu post
</div>
<div class="post">
Esse é o seu post
</div>
```